# Where in Retrofit build the full JSON before sending it?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit an get Bad Request , I would want to know if there is a place in this library where builds the full JSON in string format before sending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's about inspecting the JSON at runtime for debugging purposes, you can call `setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)` on your `RestAdapter.Builder`.

`FULL` [logs the headers, body and metadata for both requests and responses](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RestAdapter.LogLevel.html) to logcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
new String(((TypedByteArray) request.getBody()).getBytes());
```

Comment: but a specific place , because i use to call it something like this 

  serviceTwo.websiteArticlesGet(articlesGetRequest, new Callback<ArticlesResponse>() {
            Override
            public void success(ArticlesResponse articlesResponse, Response response) {
                showSuccessToast();
            }

            Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                showErrorToast();
            }
        });

Comment: Can you please update the question with this information. Then, it'll be easier for other to answer into the point. Otherwise we could only answer as a generic question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build a JSON formatted body, create an object with a class whose properties are the same that you want to send to the server. The GSON Library set up (or whichever library you are using) with the RestAdapter should send the request with the body in JSON format.

Also ensure that the call is @POST annotated and the parameter annotd with @Body Below is an example:

```
    @POST("/login")
    User login(@Body LoginUser loginUser);
```